# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del texto en C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, windows10

En primer lugar quiero avisar de que estoy empezando con C++.

Estoy intentando aprender como controlar el color de salida usando std::cout y he encontrado la siguiente manera usando lo que muestro a continuación:

```
void setConsoleColor(WORD c)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}
```

Después en el main llamo a la función como muestro en el siguiente código y ya estaría.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    setConsoleColor(3);
    std::cout << "Introduce un número entero: ";
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que "SetConsoleTextAttribute" hace necesario tener el #include <windows.h> y este me obliga a ir en contra del tutorial que sigo para aprender. En el tutorial me dicen que en Visual Studio es muy recomendable tener deshabilitadas las extensiones de lenguaje pero si las tengo deshabilitadas el #include <windows.h> no compila.

En resumen quiero saber si hay una forma de cambiar el color de texto de salida sin emplear windows.h para no tener que habilitar dichas extensiones. Aquí dejo un link para que podáis ver el tutorial donde dice que deshabilitarlas está altamente recomendado y porque:

[Enlace al tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-compiler-extensions/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053837/colorizing-text-in-the-console-with-c

Comment: Lo que te dice en tu tutorial es que si quieres hacer algo standard c++ que compile en todos los sistemas operativos y con todos los compiladores, obviamente no puedes usar nada de Windows porque eso no sería compatible en otro sistema operativo. Pero si tienes que usar el API de windows, no te queda otra que incluir windows.h. Podrías hacer algo para que en windows se compilara una parte de tu código y en otro sistema otro, pero en la parte de windows tendrás que incluir el windows.h.